# VisualVM - Heap dump greyed out

Tags: visualvm

Issue: Once connected to application, the option for perform GC is enabled button. However the heap dump button is greyed out. Also in the "application" menu its greyed out. Does it work for apps connected via jmx locally?

Description: Connecting via jmx to a websphere application. Stats and data come back but I want to see what's in memory for objects to look at a class object size. Heap dump button is greyed out.

Version: VisualVM 2.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you are running a websphere on OpenJ9/IBM JDK. This will explain why heap dump is not available - unfortunately OpenJDK and OpenJ9 are substantially different in